# How to convert .htacess(apache) to Nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

I try convert on [site](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) but i dont' have sucess.
I need convert .htacess code for Nginx code.
My .htacess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine   On
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule     ^(.*)$  index.php?url=$1    [PT,L,QSA]

    ErrorDocument 400 error.html?err=404
    ErrorDocument 401 error.html?err=401
    ErrorDocument 403 error.html?err=403
    ErrorDocument 404 error.html?err=404
    ErrorDocument 500 error.html?err=500
    ErrorDocument 503 error.html?err=503
</IfModule>
```

My nginx code is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.mysite.com.*;
        index index.php;
        root /home/mysite1/public_html/mysite/webapp/;
        client_max_body_size 5M;


        if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
                break;
        }

        location / {                    
                             try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?url=$uri&$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

       }
}
```

My php code is:

```
<?php
define('APP_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS);
    define('CFG_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'config' . DS);
    define('LIB_PATH', __DIR__ . DS . 'lib' . DS);
    define('RES_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'resources' . DS);
    define('TMP_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'tmp' . DS);
    define('VND_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS);

    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';

    require_once(VND_PATH . 'autoload.php');
    require_once(CFG_PATH . 'config.php');
    require_once(CFG_PATH . 'routing.php');
    require_once(__DIR__ . DS . 'doctrine.php');
    require_once(__DIR__ . DS . 'autoloader.php');

    Cache::createDirs();

    session_start();

    $dfgfw = new DFGFW();

    $dfgfw->gzipOutput() || ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
    $dfgfw->setReporting();
    $dfgfw->removeMagicQuotes();
    $dfgfw->exec();
```

Access to the site works.
mysite.mysite.com

Route system doesn't working.
mysite.mysite.com/history

What is wrong with my Nginx and how can I work with the Codeigniter internal route system?

Comment: Get rid of the `if` block completely, your `location` block does that with the `try` command which says "try this request as a file, then a directory, and then pass it on to `index.php`"

Answer (score 0):

Try [this converter](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx). This would yield the correct `try_files` directive (the corner-stone of NGINX front-pattern URL rewriting):

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I can get the parameter on `$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';` but i get status code 404 in mysite.mysite.com/history.

Comment: You still need `location ~ \.php$ { ... ` to pass through PHP requests to PHP-FPM.

Comment: Yes, I do it here: `location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;` I have a new problem?